# Evaluate $\int \frac{\cos^{2}x-\sin x}{\cos x\left ( 1+\cos xe^{\sin x} \right )}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate
$$\int \frac{\cos^{2}x-\sin x}{\cos x\left ( 1+\cos xe^{\sin x} \right )}dx$$
I don't know where to start.A little help will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\int \frac{\cos^{2}x-\sin x}{\cos x\left ( 1+\cos xe^{\sin x} \right )}\, \mathrm{d}x=\int \frac{e^{\sin x}\left (\cos^{2}x-\sin x  \right )}{\cos xe^{\sin x}\left ( 1+\cos xe^{\sin x} \right )}\, \mathrm{d}x=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}\left ( \cos xe^{\sin x} \right )}{\cos xe^{\sin x}\left ( 1+\cos xe^{\sin x} \right )}$$
Then you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful hint again!